# UIButton changing width when label changes

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibutton

I'm writing a calculator app with a shift key. When the shift key is pressed, some of the UIButtons' labels should change. The problem is that when they do, the widths also change and, because of certain design constraints, other buttons will resize themselves too. How to I lock the width of a button (either pragmatically or in the storyboard builder) so that it will never change (regardless of the contents of the button)

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons, like labels have an intrinsic size that's set by the width of their text plus some padding. If you want them to have a fixed width, then in IB, just give each button an explicit width from the menu, Editor --> Pin --> Width.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `[button sizeToFit]`? Call it after you resize the subviews within and then you will likely want to apply some "padding" as this will size the view to exactly fit it's subviews.

[UIView sizeToFit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit)